# Django admin does not login properly with custom User model

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.5

I upgraded an app I had on Django 1.4.5 to Django 1.5 and just finished migrating over to a custom User model. When I login to my app, using my own authentication form, with my superuser credentials (created when doing `manage.py syncdb`) everything works fine.

I am able to get authenticated and if I go to `/admin`, I am already logged in, as expected. I am able to navigate and use the Admin panel perfectly. However, if I try to login to the admin panel from `/admin`, using the django admin login form, I get the error:

> Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note
>   that both fields may be case-sensitive.

I did some investigating and thought it could have something to do with `ModelAdmin`, so I followed [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) from the docs and created a custom `ModelAdmin`. However, the problem still persists.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: You have AUTH_USER_MODEL set in settings.py, right?

Comment: Yup, I've got that set.

Comment: Did you use `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` for your User model extension?

Comment: I used `AbstractBaseUser`.

Comment: the superuser must be equal to True that's why you can't login in the admin page

Answer (score 10):

Did you add following lines in to your `create_superuser` function which is under `BaseUserManager`? It might look like this:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Dude you need a username.')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(
                'type an e-mail..')

        new_user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=CustomUserManager.normalize_email(email))
        new_user.set_password(password)
        new_user.save(using=self._db)
        return new_user

  def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        new = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            password=password
        )
        new.is_active = True
        new.is_staff = True
        new.is_superuser = True
        new.save(using=self._db)
        return new
```

Focus on:

```
    new.is_active = True
    new.is_staff = True
    new.is_superuser = True
```

Comment: django's admin checks for `request.user.is_active` and `request.user.is_staff` to log users in, so I think he should add `new.is_active=True` to that list to "focus on".

Comment: When i do is_staff = True instead of is_staff = False. Admin login works for me!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues but I found @alix's answer so helpfully. I had forgotten to add `is_active=True on create_superuser()`

```
def create_staffuser(self, email, first_name=None, last_name=None, user_role=None, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        user_role=user_role,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
        is_active=True
    )
    return user
```

so basically you need to focus on is_active and check your

```
# changes the in-build User model to ours (Custom)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by custom User model, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this part did the tick. Thanks for the pointers on these @gregoltsov

```
obj.is_active = True
obj.is_staff = True
obj.is_admin = True
```

What I was missing was the **obj.is_active** part.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    user = self.create_user(username, email, password=password, is_staff=True, **extra_fields)
    user.is_active = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return
```

please vote if it works for you.