# Django Custom Auth Model can't login from Admin portal

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've created custom user profile model for Django's auth app, and the issue that I can't login using Django Admin login form.

Note: User `is_superuser=1` and `is_staff=1`

```
models.py
=======================
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, verbose_name='Gender', default=1)
    civil_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, verbose_name='Civil ID')
    tel_num = models.CharField(max_length=18, blank=True, verbose_name='Telephone Number')
    mob_num = models.CharField(max_length=18, verbose_name='Mobile Number')
    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of birth', null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name='Country', null=True)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, verbose_name='Province', null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, verbose_name='Area', null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, verbose_name='Profile Image', default='')
    secondary_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Secondary Email',
                                        help_text='This email address will be used in case of account recovery',
                                        blank=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Verified', default=False)
    verification_request = models.CharField(max_length=25, default=generate_verification_code)
    is_in_smart_launch = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Is profile created in smartlaunch')
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, related_name='users', null=True)
```

and in saving the userprofile im using `set_password()`

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I would ask you to inspect your database (if it is SQLite, then there exist a bunch of db inspection tools) and post what the username and password is in the db.

Answer (score 2):

[from this post django looks up the model prop for is_superuser, is_active and is_staff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181379/django-admin-does-not-login-properly-with-custom-user-model/15593318)

```
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
superuser = models.BooleanField(default=True)

@property
def is_superuser(self):
    return self.superuser

@property
def is_active(self):
    return self.active

@property
def is_staff(self):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use admin login if the user is not a staff member (as the error sais).
If you want a built in login page you can probably use `/accounts/login` which is the default value for `settings.LOGIN_URL`

Comment: This user is already a staff member and created using createsuperuser command

Comment: but you wrote: User is_superuser=0 and is_staff=0

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `password=None`, by `password` and pass `'password=password'` into the `create_user` function as you see below, together with `'username=username'`:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Please add an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Please add an username')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(
            email), username=username, password=password)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(
            email), username=username, password=password)

        user.is_active = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

I can't see your whole code but I assume it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem while defining a custom User without the `username` field. After setting both `is_admin` and `is_staff` fields, the admin login page worked again. My code looks like below

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):                                  
    """                                                                            
    A custom class for user authentication. It gets rid of 
    'username' and uses 'email' for that purpose.                                                      
    """                                                                            
    email = models.EmailField(                                                     
         max_length=64,                                                             
        unique=True)                                    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True,)          
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                  
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                  

    objects = MyUserManager()                                                      

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'                                                       
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []                                                           

    def __str__(self):                                                             
        return self.email                                                          
    # more code below omitted
```